# Androidプロジェクトでのxmlファイルの書き方。または、プログラム上、Rと表記されている何か（インスタンス）の作り方

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
を使って、JAVAの文法から、勉強（実験）に手を付け始めてみました。

https://qiita.com/qiiChan/items/5d94ceb99bfc390c6372
を見ながら、ソースをコピペ

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //オブジェクト
    private Button btnSend;
    private TextView textInput;
    private TextView textOutput;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        textInput = findViewById(R.id.textInput);
        textOutput = findViewById(R.id.textOutput);
```

して動くかな？と試してみているレベルの実験をしているのですが、さっそくいくつかのエラーでつまずき、今は下記のエラーでつまずいています。

> C:\＜略＞\example\testapp001\MainActivity.java:22:
> エラー: シンボルを見つけられません
> btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
> ^   シンボル:   変数 btnSend   場所: クラス id

C:\＜略＞\TestApp001\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
の中を見ても、"R"一文字で定義された何かはみあたりません。（このファイルは、私は一度も入れていない状態です）

このエラーはどいういう意味ですか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

レイアウトファイル `res/layout/activity_main.xml` に

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
```

とある、`@+id/btnSend` がそれです。ビルド時に自動的に `R.id.btnSend` として登録されます。